# Navigation item always jumping out of a top bar (CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-float, nav

I have been sweating over this crazy black magic.

[image]

The "bla bla" is a `<nav>` that is inside my `<div class="top_bar">` (the blue bar) and when I add `float:right` to the nav, it jumps to the right and out of the bar.

```
<div class="top_bar">
    <a href="#"><h3>Nafame / <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h3></a>

    <span></span>

    <nav>
        <a href="#">bla bla</a>
        <a href="#">bla bla</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The weird thing is that I can "fix" that with 2 options:

a) If I remove `<h3>` tag from the title it pops back in.
b) If I add a random `<span>hello</span>` between title and nav. (the image below is using option b).

[image]

This is my CSS:

```
.top_bar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

nav {
    float: right;
}
```

The file where this top_bar is, is included at the top of my header file and the content of that file is all I posted above. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header elements display block which means they take up 100% of the width if you set it to inline it will allow you nav to be to the right of it instead of below.

EDIT:It works with the span because spans are inline by default.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header

```css
.top_bar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

nav {
    float: right;   
}
h3{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_bar">
  <a href="#">
    <h3>Nafame /
      <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
    </h3>
  </a>

  <span></span>

  <nav>
    <a href="#">bla bla</a>
    <a href="#">bla bla</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, makes total sense. But why would it also work if there is a <span> with some text? Is it because the block is now bigger and it coincidentally fits the "bla bla"?
Thanks anyway @Scath

Comment: You don't have to make a block element as inline, especially `h3` or any other header tags. Use div instead as parent of heading and set the width.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to put `nav` into `.top_bar`, use an inline element or a block/inline element such as a `div` and set the width to some `%`.

Below I have updated `<h3>` with `<span>`

```css
.top_bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_bar">
  <a href="#">
    <span>Nafame /
      <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
    </span>
  </a>

  <nav>
    <a href="#">bla bla</a>
    <a href="#">bla bla</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked in a sense that it made the bar bigger and included the "bla bla", but it doesnt remain inline with the title. The solution above is better for this situation. Thank you, still! @bhansa

Comment: I have updated the answer, feel free to ask if any doubts.